# Problema com zIndex JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css3

O script será um banner rotativo dois botões: avançar e voltar.

Estou começando a conhecer melhor o JavaScript e tenho uma dúvida. Por que é que ele não reconhece o AnteSlide e o ProxSlide?

Segue o código:

```js
 var primeiraExecusao = true;
 var slideAtual = 0;
 var proxSlide = 0;
 var anteSlide = 0;
 var timeOut = '';
 x = document.getElementsByClassName('img'); 
 function Temporizador(initiate) {
  proxSlide = slideAtual + 1;
  anteSlide = slideAtual - 1;
  if(slideAtual == x.length){
   proxSlide = 0;
  }else if(slideAtual == 0){
   anteSlide = x.length;
  }
  x[anteSlide].style.zIndex = '5';
  x[proxSlide].style.zIndex = '7';
  alert(anteSlide + " - " + proxSlide + " - " + slideAtual + " - " + x.length);
  x[slideAtual].style.zIndex = '10';
  
  if(primeiraExecusao == true){
   primeiraExecusao = false;
   x[slideAtual].style.display = 'block';
  }else{
   x[slideAtual].style.display = 'block';
  }
  
  if(slideAtual == x.length){
   timeOut = setTimeout(Desativa, 5500);
  }else{
   timeOut = setTimeout(Temporizador, 5500);
  }
  slideAtual++;
 }
 
 
 function Desativa(){
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
   x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  primeiraExecusao = true;
  timeOut = setTimeout(Temporizador, 100);
 }
 function avancar(){
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  /*if(slideAtual == x.length){
   slideAtual = 0;
  }else{
   slideAtual + 1;
  }
  timeOut = setTimeout(Temporizador, 100);*/
 }
 function voltar(){
  clearTimeout(timeOut);
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
   x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  if(slideAtual == 0){
   slideAtual = x.length;
  }else{
   slideAtual - 1;
  }
 }
 $(function() {
  Temporizador(true);
 });
```

```css
 body{
  background-color: green;
 }
 .img{
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 5.5s;
  z-index: auto;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .0}
  to {opacity: 1}
 }
 @keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .0}
  to {opacity: 1}
 }
 .lastSlide{
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeout;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5.5s;
  animation-name: fadeout;
  animation-duration: 5.5s;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
  from {opacity: 1}
  to {opacity: 0}
 }
 @keyframes fadeout {
  from {opacity: 1}
  to {opacity: 0}
 }
 .fundo{
  max-width: 50%;
  min-width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: pink;
 }
 .um{
  
 }
 .dois{
  
 }
 .desativado{
  display: none;
 }
 .setas{
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.4;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: white;
 }
 .setas:hover{
  opacity: 0.8
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/slide.css'/>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/slide.js'></script>
</head>
<body onload="Temporizador(true)">
 <div class='img um'><img src='img/slide/img1.jpg'></div>
 <div class='img dois'><img src='img/slide/img2.jpg'></div>
 <div class='img um desativado'><img src='img/slide/img3.jpg'></div>
 <span class='setas anterior' onclick='voltar()'><</span>
 <span class='setas posterior' onclick='acancar()'>></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu os declarei antes de iniciar a função, para que essas variáveis pudessem ser utilizadas por outras funções. 
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: OBS: Meu problema atual é esta questão do zIndex. As funções abaixo ainda não estão corretas.

Comment: Você conseguiu uma resposta para sua pergunta?

Comment: Não consegui trabalhar com o z-index e também não consegui fazer o sistema reconhecer as variáveis que informo. Utilizei outra estratégia para criar o banner.

Comment: Ok. Coloque uma resposta para sua pergunta, para assim ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1):

Analisando o código, acabei percebendo que utilizar o z-index seria confuso. Utilizei o transition dentro do css e a seguinte formula dentro do JAVASCRIPT

```
var slideAtual = 0;
var timeOut = '';
var ajustaZIndex = 0;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('exibe');
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('pass');
Temporizador(true);
function Temporizador(initiate) {
    if(slideAtual == x.length){
        for(var i = 0; i <= (x.length - 1); i++){
            x[i].style.display = 'none';
            y[i].classList.remove('ativo');
        }
        timeOut = setTimeout(Temporizador, 0500);
        slideAtual = 0;
    }else{

        y[slideAtual].classList.add('ativo');
        x[slideAtual].style.display = 'block';
        timeOut = setTimeout(Temporizador, 5500);
        slideAtual++;
    }
}
function banner(n){
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    slideAtual = n;
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        x[i].style.display = 'none';
        y[i].classList.remove('ativo');
    }
    y[slideAtual].classList.add('ativo');
    x[n].style.display = 'block';
    timeOut = setTimeout(Temporizador, 2500);

}
$(function() {
    Temporizador(true);
});
```